# How are the bounds of the natural logarithm function determined?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I just read a proof which argued that since the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $1/x$, it follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $\ln(x) = \int_1^x 1/t dt$.

Now, supposing it is indeed the case that

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$

How do you know, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, that

$$
\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} d?
$$

That is, how do you know that the bounds of the integral should be from $1$ to $x$ as opposed to any other $a \in \mathbb{R}$ to $x$?

Comment: In general, $\int_a^x (1/t) dt = \ln(x) - \ln(a)$ (assuming $a$ and $x$ are positive). Note that if $a=1$ then $\ln(a) = 0$.

Comment: In addition to Bungo's remark, this is how the natural log is Defined. Your first sentence in your post should be read the other way.

Comment: @imranfat It's not true that $\ln x$ is always defined that way.

Comment: @zhw. Complex numbers excluded, it is one way how to introduce the natural log. And for a calculus student, it is in my view certainly more elegant  to introduce it Bungo's way, than to introduce the natural log defined to be the inverse of the e-power, which is what I understandably see in pre calculus textbooks. Arguably it depends on the audience in the class room...